# Composite key / secondary indexing strategy in Redis

Tags: data-structures, redis

Say I have some data of the following sort that I want to store in Redis:

```
* UUID
* State (e.g. PROCESSED, WAITING_FOR_RESPONSE)
* […] other vals
```

The `UUID` or the `State` are the only two variables that I will ever need to query on

- What data structure in Redis is most suited for this?
- How would I go about structuring the keys?

Comment: What's your main "key" that you would use to access the object? If you need to query for UUID, what are you going to use to query? Is there some other id? Sorry more specifically, I'm not too clear on what you mean by query, are you saying you'd want "Give me items with state `PROCESSED`" or give me state of X?

Comment: Only that UUID or the state, `123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000-*` or `*-PROCESSED`. (Not sure if this makes it clearer :)

Comment: Exactly. Both of these two

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, not sure I understand completely but going to try to go with it.

Assuming you need to look up all entities with state `PROCESSED` you can use sets for these:

```
SADD PROCESSED 123-abcd-4567-0000
```

Then you can easily find all entities with `PROCESSED` state. You'll do same for each state you want.

```
SMEMBERS PROCESSED
```

Now you'll also then want to have a hash for all your entities and its values:

```
HSET 123-abcd-4567-0000 state PROCESSED
HSET 123-abcd-4567-0000 otherproperty valuedata
```

This will set the "state" in the hash for the UUID to be processed (you'll need to figure out how to keep these in sync, you can use scripts or just handle in your code)

So in summary you have 2 major structures:

1. Sets to store your State to UUID information

   - Thus you have 1 set per state
2. Hashes to store the UUID to properties information

   - Thus you have 1 hash PER entity

Example Hash

```
123-abcd-4567-0000 => { state: PROCESSED, active: true }
987-zxy-1234-0000 => { state: PROCESSED, active: false }
```

But please clarify more if this doesn't seem to fit.

---

If you want to reduce your key space since the Hashes per entity can be much you can create a hash per attribute instead:

```
HSET states 123-abcd-4567-0000 PROCESSED
```

Thus you have a hash per attribute and your key is the UUID and value is the value of the property which is the hash key.

Example Hash

```
state => { 123-abcd-4567-0000: PROCESSED, 987-zxy-1234-0000: PROCESSED }
active => { 123-abcd-4567-0000: true, 987-zxy-1234-0000: false }
```

Comment: Note that SMEMBERS returns all the members in a Set, so if the cardinality is high this could become an expensive operation. In such cases, you should consider reverting to SSCAN in its stead.

Answer (score 1):

[RediSearch](https://redisearch.io) (a [Redis module](https://redis.io/modules)) supports adding secondary index to existing data in Redis like Hash.

After setting the schema for the fiels you would like to index you can easily search based on these fields values.

e.g.

```sh
127.0.0.1:6379> FT.CREATE myIdx ON HASH PREFIX 1 doc: SCHEMA title TEXT

127.0.0.1:6379> hset doc:1 title "mytitle" body "lorem ipsum" url "http://redis.io" 
(integer) 3

127.0.0.1:6379> FT.SEARCH myIdx "@title:mytitle" LIMIT 0 10
1) (integer) 1
2) "doc:1"
3) 1) "title"
   2) "mytitle"
   3) "body"
   4) "lorem ipsum"
   5) "url"
   6) "http://redis.io"
```